# My SELECT and other two queries work slowly

Tags: mysql, select

I have two tables:

table1

```
id  |   field1  |id_order   |
----------------------------------  
1   |   value1  |   null    |
2   |   value2  |   null    |
3   |   value3  |   999     |
4   |   value4  |   888     |
5   |   value5  |   null    |
6   |   value6  |   777     |
```

and table2

```
id  |id_order   |name   | total
------------------------------------------- 
1   |   999     |name1  |100    |
2   |   999     |name2  |300    |
3   |   777     |name3  |700    |
4   |   888     |name4  |400    |
5   |   888     |name5  |500    |
6   |   888     |name6  |200    |
```

result must be

```
id  |   field1      |total_count    |   last_value
---------------------------------------------------------   
1   |   value1      |null           |   null    |
2   |   value2      |null           |   null    |
3   |   value3      |2              |   300     |
4   |   value4      |3              |   200     |
5   |   value5      |null           |   null    |
6   |   value6      |1              |   700     |
```

I want to get count and last value. Here is my code, but it works slowly:

```
 SELECT  *,
     (select count(*) from table2 where table2.id_order=table1.id_order and table1.id_order > 0 group by id_order ) as total_count,
     (select total from table2 where table2.id_order=table1.id_order and table1.id_order>0 order by id DESC limit 1) as last_value 
    FROM table1
```

Comment: It's not possible that `*` can return your desired result. See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: SELECT  id, field1,
     (select count(*) from table2 where table2.id_order=table1.id_order and table1.id_order > 0 group by id_order ) as total_count,
     (select total from table2 where table2.id_order=table1.id_order and table1.id_order>0 order by id DESC limit 1) as last_value 
    FROM table1;

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;

CREATE TABLE table1
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,field1 VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,id_order INT NULL
);

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES
(1,'value1',null),
(2,'value2',null),
(3,'value3',999),
(4,'value4',888),
(5,'value5',null),
(6,'value6',777);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table2;

CREATE TABLE table2
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,id_order INT NOT NULL
,name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,total INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO table2 VALUES
(1,999,'name1',100),
(2,999,'name2',300),
(3,777,'name3',700),
(4,888,'name4',400),
(5,888,'name5',500),
(6,888,'name6',200);

SELECT x.id
     , x.field1
     , y.total_count
     , y.total 
  FROM table1 x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT a.*
            , b.total_count 
         FROM table2 a 
         JOIN 
            ( SELECT MAX(id) id
                   , COUNT(*) total_count 
                FROM table2 
               GROUP 
                  BY id_order
            ) b 
           ON b.id = a.id
      ) y 
     ON y.id_order = x.id_order;

+----+--------+-------------+-------+
| id | field1 | total_count | total |
+----+--------+-------------+-------+
|  1 | value1 |        NULL |  NULL |
|  2 | value2 |        NULL |  NULL |
|  3 | value3 |           2 |   300 |
|  4 | value4 |           3 |   200 |
|  5 | value5 |        NULL |  NULL |
|  6 | value6 |           1 |   700 |
+----+--------+-------------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```